# App takes a long time to load when launched with URL scheme

Tags: ios, url-scheme

When another app launches my app using the URL scheme it takes too much time to launch (splash screen displayed for around 5-7s).

What could be causing the delay?

Comment: Show your `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`  method

Comment: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
   NSlog@“another app launched our app”);
   return YES;
}

Comment: I am not doing any task in the method right now.Just printing a NSLog and returning YES. This method gets call after 8-10 sec. So i dont think there is something wrong in my code. What do you think ?

Comment: can you also debug `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method? how much time is needed to get it called?

Comment: In my project application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions: is not present. application:DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions: is there but it does not get call before 7-8 seconds.

Comment: Can you show a code that call `openURL:completionHandler:`?